# Two identical values not treated equally in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup, cell-format

Was trying to use a simple VLOOKUP on a table with some calculated values (using formulas). It couldn't do exact match, even though the lookup value is equal to the table value. But copying the needed table cell, and using that cell as a reference for lookup value works. 
Recreated the issue in a simple table (see attached), but copied over one of the table cells from the original (so, it's not a formula anymore). Also copied the original table cell again to the lookup cell. Lookup works. Editing the cell (but not changing anything) and pressing enter breaks the lookup. 
The attached table shows these two look ups next to each other. The two cells are identically formatted, and values are equal to each other. And yet one works and the other doesn't.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_H0r_KuPwzAby1OS05XSGMwaHc

Comment: The displayed value is rounded and displayed as allowed by the cell's formating.  The actual value may carry many more digits beyond the decimal point.  The actual value is used formulas in other cells, not the displayed value.

Comment: Don't understand your point, @Tyson . The value in the table is no longer a formula, but a value. And I made sure to show all of its digits. But just to check, comparing these values in a blank cell "=C7=D14" ([table cell] = [lookup cell 1]) and "=C7=D15" ([table cell] = [lookup cell 2]) and "=D14=D15" ([lookup cell 1] = [lookup cell 2]) returns true for all cases. So it's can't be a value issue, if Excel confirms that all 3 values are equal.